# Unable to make a custom radio control a part of the radio group that already contains dynamic generated radio controls

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

Here is a link to the code that is referenced below in my question - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gtztx?file=/demo.tsx

In the code below (or `demo.tsx` from the codesandbox link above ), I am trying to combine a new `FormControlLabel` radio button (line 24) into the dynamically generated material UI radio buttons.
I don't want to add this new radio button into the "options" list within "index.tsx", but I still want this new radio button to be within the same "payment" radio group.

**Current behavior:** After the page renders, this custom radio with the label as Unknown always remains checked.

**Expected behavior:** Make this custom radio button work as a part of the dynamically created "payment" radio groups without adding it to the "options" list (see index.tsx)

```
export default function RadioButtonsGroup(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  console.log(value);
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Payment</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="payment"
        name="payment1"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {/* <FormControlLabel value={value} control={<Radio />} label="Unknown" /> */}
        {props.options.map(([value, readable], index) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={index}
            value={value}
            control={<Radio />}
            label={readable}
          />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jgopr

Basically, I added a `checked` prop to all the radio buttons (the custom one and the ones in the `optionList`) to correctly show the selected state of radio control for the `value` in the component state.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I accepted your answer.  Apologies for the delayed response.